# CSS div in bottom not showing if applied margin

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I was able to replicate the image but only if my div is not floating in the page (without the margin applied and without the `position: absolute`), otherwise I can't see the green rectangle.

My HTML structure is the following:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="interface">
    <div class="view">
      <div class="body">
        <div class="top">
          Top content
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          Middle content
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            Bottom content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the `.interface` CSS I have the following:

```
.interface
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}
```

With this CSS I'm unable to see the green rectangle. If I remove the `position: absolute` (and therefore the `top: 15%` stops applying) I'm able to see the green rectangle.

You can see the issue in this **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/v9euwdz3/

So, how do I manage to have the DIV showing at a certain level (margin from top) and without compromise my HTML structure?

Comment: margin-top:15vh? and you can get rid of position:absolute

Comment: @TemaniAfif does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're trying to achieve using flex:

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navetc {
  background-color: white;
  height: 15vh;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="interface">
    <div class="view">
      <div class="body">
        <div class="navetc">
          SPACE
        </div>
        <div class="top">
          Top content
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          Middle content
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          Bottom content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use `margin-top: 15%;` instead of a placeholder div

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  margin-top: 15vh;
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="interface">
    <div class="view">
      <div class="body">
        <div class="top">
          Top content
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          Middle content
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          Bottom content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I used vh instead of % to get it to show up correctly in this code snippet)

Comment: Does not work when I copy-paste into the JSFiddle (it has the same behavior)

Comment: Works for me... Could you be more descriptive about what is not working? The console may be covering it up for you. Open the settings in the top right and turn off "Console in the Editor" Here it is in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyirons/nd69uv1w/

Comment: You just deleted my code of `html`, `app`, `interface`, `view`. https://jsfiddle.net/cj0kgq9v/, if you expand the bottom disappears.

Answer (score 0):

as we know the content that have height which is `100%` means is `100%` of its parent and while the height of the parent is not defined will cause an error that's what you was stuck with you set the with of `body` to `100%` but was not right you would set it to `100vh` to fit the screen if you are on computer and the other mistakes that I found was in your calculation where you used to subtract the measurement which is in parcentages from the one in pixels `height: calc(100% - 150px);` and the others where simple mistakes

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.interface {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 15%;
}

.view {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 350px;
}

.body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.body .top {
  height: 15%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.body .middle {
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body .bottom {
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="interface">
    <div class="view">
      <div class="body">
        <div class="top">
          Top content
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          Middle content
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          Bottom content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to see the result in the snippet you should observe it in full page and also when you see the result through jsfiddle there at the result section there is bar downward which hide some part of `footer`

Comment: The problem is that with your example (playing with percentages) does not work exactly the same in different resolutions.

Comment: use media queries if you want to but I hope on computer it works fine